# javascript submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, validation

I have a form with about 4 Question, each have 2 answers to choose from - radio button type.

(1)Do you want milk?
Yes 
No

(2)Are you happy?
Yes 
No

(3)Do you have parents?
Yes 
No

(4)Do you have sisters?
Yes 
No

(1) first i will like to have a javascript or jquery validation to make sure each question have an answer chosen, the form should not be submited with a null value.

(20) if a user chooses Yes for any of the question, it takes them to a Yes.html page
     if the user chooses No, then it takes them to a No.html. For them to get to the No.html, they will have to choose all No answers for each question

so Yes, is the higher preference here..

Please help.

I want this, but with validation to make sure all is selected:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function choosePage() {
        if(document.getElementById('weightloss').form1_option1.checked) {
            window.location.replace( "http://google.com/" );
        }
        if(document.getElementById('weightloss').form1_option2.checked) {
            window.location.replace( "http://yahoo.com/" );
        }
    }
</script>

<form id="weightloss">
     <input type="radio" id="form1_option1" name="weight-loss" value="5_day" class="plan">
     <label for="form1_option1"> 5 Day - All Inclusive Price</label><br>
     <input type="radio" id="form1_option2" name="weight-loss" value="7_day">
     <label for="form1_option2"> 7 Day - All Inclusive Price</label><br>
     <input type="button" value="Place Order" alt="Submit button" class="orange_btn" onclick="choosePage()">
</form>
```

Comment: Do you have anything you tried yet?  Or some existing markup/script?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form onsubmit="validate(this); return false;">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Do you want milk?</td>
                <td>Yes<input type="radio" name="milk"  class="Yes" /> No <input type="radio" name="milk" class="No" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Are you happy?</td>
                <td>Yes<input type="radio" name="happy" class="Yes" /> No <input type="radio" name="happy" class="No" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Do you have parents?</td>
                <td>Yes<input type="radio" name="parents" class="Yes" /> No <input type="radio" name="parents" class="No" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Do you have sisters?</td>
                <td>Yes<input type="radio" name="sisters" class="sisters" /> No <input type="radio" name="sisters" class="No" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Done" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validate(form) {
        var hasYes = false;
        var counter = 0;
        $("input:checked", form).each(function() {
            if ($(this).hasClass("Yes")) {
                hasYes = true;
            }
            counter++;
        });
        if (hasYes == true || counter != 4)
            window.location = "Yes.html";
        else
            window.location = "No.html";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: just add a counter and make sure you have 4 checked boxes.

Comment: i dont know men, but this still dont work...its frustrating me

Comment: You are very vague on your questions and answers. I can't help you if you don't give me detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some html:

```
<form name="myForm" id="formId">
    <span>Do you want milk?</span>
    <input type="radio" name="milk" value="yes" /><label>yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="milk" value="no" /><label>no</label>

    <span>Are you happy?</span>
    <input type="radio" name="happy" value="yes" /><label>yes</label>
    <input type="radio" name="happy" value="no" /><label>no</label>
```

and so on until...

```
    <a onclick="validate();">Click here to submit</a>
</form>
```

and your javascript:

```
function validate(){
    var data = $("#formId").serialize();
    var field;
    for (field in data){
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(field)){
            if (data[field] == "yes"){
                window.location = "yes.html";  
                return;  
            }
        }
    }
    window.location = "no.html";
    return;
}
```

Comment: You need to give a little more information than 'its not working'. You still haven't provided any markup or code that you have started with for us to help fix.

Comment: This is what i had for the validation

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to make sure each named radio button group is checked you could use something like the following:

```
var names = [];
$("input[type=radio]").each(function() {
    if (!!$.inArray($(this).attr("name"), names)) {
        names.push($(this).attr("name"));
    }
});
var $checkedRadio = $.map(names, function(name) {
    return $("input[name=" + name + "]:checked");
});

if(names.length !== $checkedRadio.length){
    //dont submit
    return false;
}
```

Example of this working on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/hpR22/5/).